# Can I use FsXaml with .NET 4.0?

Tags: f#, fsxaml

[FsXaml](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml) seems to be available only for projects targeting at least .NET 4.5.
It there a way to use it while targeting .NET 4.0?
If so how can I achieve this?

Comment: Given Reed Copsey's answer, is there a reason you *need* to target .NET 4.0 and cannot target 4.5 or later?

Comment: @rmunn I'm working on an addin for an application that runs on .NET 4.0.

Comment: @rmunn If you install .net 4.5.2, it's an _in place_ upgrade of .NET 4 - so you can safely use 4.5+ features in an add on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 4.0 is not supported by FsXaml. Given that [.NET 4.0 is no longer supported by Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/), I did not feel the need to try to support FsXaml in that version of the framework.

> It there a way to use it while targeting .NET 4.0?
>
> If so how can I achieve this?

It may be possible to rebuild this and target .NET 4.0. However, this will likely require modification of project files, and elimination of newer F# features that are used in the library. However, [the source code is available](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml), so you are more than welcome to attempt a port to target .NET 4 if you so choose.